# Question ending with "no?" -- can I use "n da?" instead, among friends?

Tags: particles, questions, casual

I know what "no da" and "n da" are for. When I hear the question something like "nani wo shite iru no?" from a friend, I wonder: can the question "nani wo shite iru n da?" be used instead? Do they mean exactly the same meaning or is there **any difference in connotation**?

or

```
doko e iku no? --> doko e iku n da?
```

In other words,  can "(na) no?" always be replaced with "(na) n da?" **in a question** when talking to friends? Will this soound a bit more direct and masculine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In other words, can "(na) no?" always be replaced with "(na) n da?" in a question when talking to friends? Will this sound a bit more direct and masculine?

Yes. Exactly. It sounds a bit more direct and masculine.

If you are a man, you can almost always exchange each other.

On the other hand, if you are a woman, you had better not replace "(na) no?" with "(na) n da?". It sounds weird.

Comment: `it sounds a bit more indirect and masculine.` --> why indirect? you meant more direct rather?

Comment: Oops! Sorry. I made a mistake. It's typo for "direct." I'll edit this answer.　Thank you for letting me know!